# Why Emacs adds new lines at the end of the file while pressing the down arrow?

Tags: emacs

How is it possible to avoid emacs to add *new blank lines* while pressing the <kbd>down</kbd> arrow at the end of the file?

Also, if it can help, I had to re-customize

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<up>") 'backward-paragraph)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<down>") 'forward-paragraph)
```

because this default behavior did not work.

I have GNU Emacs 24.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `next-line-add-newlines` to a false value:

```
(setq next-line-add-newlines nil)
```

(or remove the line that sets it to `t`).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any clue about why it was not the "default"?

Comment: IIRC, in recent Emacs versions the default is `nil`, but it used to be `t` in older versions.